# What is wrong with my code for this array?

Tags: java, arrays, compare

I am doing a online course and I have a problem. i do not understand what is wrong with my code. Can you please take a look and give me a hint? I don't get why the last test is not working. When they add the cat in pos 0  to the list, the list should become [cat, ape, dog, zebra], no?

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrayListMethods
{
    ArrayList<String> list; //instance variable
    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class ArrayListMethods
     */
    public ArrayListMethods(ArrayList<String> arrayList)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        list = arrayList;
    }

    /**
     * Determines if the array list is sorted (do not sort)
     * When Strings are sorted, they are in alphabetical order
     * Use the compareTo method to determine which string comes first
     * You can look at the String compareTo method in the Java API
     * @return true if the array list is sorted else false.
     */
    public boolean isSorted()
    {
        boolean sorted = true;

        // TODO: Determine if the array is sorted.
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++){
            if (list.get(i).compareTo(list.get(i + 1)) < 0){
                sorted = true;

            }
            else {
                sorted = false;
            }
        }

        return sorted;
    }
}
```

The tester class used to test the code has this:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
public class ArrayListMethodsTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //set up
        ArrayList<String> animals = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayListMethods zoo = new ArrayListMethods(animals); 
        zoo.list.add("ape");
        zoo.list.add("dog");
        soo.list.add("zebra");

        //test isSorted
        System.out.println(zoo.isSorted());
        System.out.println("Expected: true");

        zoo.list.add("cat");
        System.out.println(zoo.isSorted());
        System.out.println("Expected: false");

        zoo.list.remove("cat");
        zoo.list.add(0,"cat");
        System.out.println(zoo.isSorted());
        System.out.println("Expected: false");
}
}
```

Comment: could you include the actuall output and the expected output inside your questio?

Comment: So they are testing to see if the list is sorted or not. The output is given by the boolean. So the first test in the //test isSorted is true (code works), second test they expect false (the code works) third test they expect false  and the code gives me true...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is inside your isSorted() method, you are setting the result as false in the first iteration (because cat is not sorted). But in the second iteration it sets the result as true because "ape" is sorted compared with "dog"

The solution is to finish the process once a false is founded.

So change this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++){
    if (list.get(i).compareTo(list.get(i + 1)) < 0){
         sorted = true;
    }
    else {
         sorted = false;
    }
}
```

For this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++){
    if (list.get(i).compareTo(list.get(i + 1)) < 0){
         sorted = true;
    }
    else {
         return false;
    }
}
```

And it will work fine and it will also improve the performance, since there is no need to check the whole array. If the first couple of elements are not sorted, then the array is not sorted

Answer (score 2):

You `isSorted` method only returns false if the last two elements are not sorted. You should add a `break` after setting the `sorted` variable to false:

```
public boolean isSorted() {
    boolean sorted = true;

    // TODO: Determine if the array is sorted.
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++){
        if (list.get(i).compareTo(list.get(i + 1)) < 0){
            sorted = true;

        }
        else {
            sorted = false;
            break; // Add break here
        }
    }

    return sorted;
}
```

Or more simply:

```
public boolean isSorted() {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++){
        if (list.get(i).compareTo(list.get(i + 1)) > 0){
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```